# FB is sending me a non-URL safe code

Tags: java, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

FB is sending me a non-URL safe code. While implementing the oauth authentication, FB is sending me a code parameter that is non-url safe.

When i authorize the app i am getting the code parameter with the below value which is not url safe.

```
AQBQnGZgFNv5EcIB9hZI20GcUgBWru7TE-p_G5NB2HQLX87fyc463aM0BIAiBg_PwRiIuyo0KS1vrDLOLB_SQ0goY31RrNYtZ23lOeaOkGzztarMYH8bJpSYjFOgiXbPhcP6h9YCsizekmcbLpPX_3F7qhsZOLM37UGI7QysvyYOvptpgJ-fm5t-eSViIU_CQH8jTPcQu3BylUVIXS0cEt5T#___=_
```

When FB is redirecting the control to the my url which is a java web application, i tried to get the code parameter using the code "request.getParameter(CODE)" But i am getting only

```
AQBQnGZgFNv5EcIB9hZI20GcUgBWru7TE-p_G5NB2HQLX87fyc463aM0BIAiBg_PwRiIuyo0KS1vrDLOLB_SQ0goY31RrNYtZ23lOeaOkGzztarMYH8bJpSYjFOgiXbPhcP6h9YCsizekmcbLpPX_3F7qhsZOLM37UGI7QysvyYOvptpgJ-fm5t-eSViIU_CQH8jTPcQu3BylUVIXS0cEt5T
```

without `#___=_`

so i am not able to continue further. But i manually add it to the parameter to fetch the access token it is working fine.

Why is this happening? Please help me.

Comment: You shouldn't need the #_=_ part, that's an empty URL fragment as far as I know; what problem are you having using the code itself? (excluding the part after the #)

Comment: When i tried without  #_=_  now it is working fine                     it was showing the issue last week.                                        I hardcoded the value with the code with the parameter and it was working fine at that time.i am not sure whether that was a bug?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is signed_request code.

Comment: I didn't get that                                                            I used the url https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXX& redirect_uri=https://sjdfhskdjfhksdf.com to get the code

Comment: yes, this is not signed_request. there's no any dot on code..  facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx.com returns with code.. you can use this code like this:
`token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="&app_id&"&redirect_uri="&my_url&"&client_secret="&app_secret&"&code="&code`

`access_token = file_get_contents(token_url)`

Comment: It's indeed not the `signed_request`, it's a `code` for OAuth2.

Comment: When i tried without  #_=_  now it is working fine                     it was showing the issue last week.                                        I hardcoded the value with the code with the parameter and it was working fine at that time.i am not sure whether that was a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need the `#_=_` trail to get further, it's not a part of `signed_request` or `code` for OAuth2. If you can proceed to further steps it's something other that this.

Once you get `code` passed to `redirect_uri` URL you can continue with [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/):

> In order to authenticate your app, you must pass the authorization code and your app secret to the Graph API token endpoint - along with the exact same redirect_uri used above - at https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

Comment: I tried without the #_=_ but it is showing the invalid code exception that is i tried to get the code directly from "request.getParameter(CODE)"

Comment: When i tried without  #_=_  now it is working fine                     it was showing the issue last week.                                        I hardcoded the value with the code with the parameter and it was working fine at that time.i am not sure whether that was a bug?